# Copying a frozen object create compilation issues in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Doing the following:

```
const toto = Object.freeze({a: 1});
const tata = Object.assign({}, toto);
tata.a = 3;
console.log(toto,  Object.isFrozen(toto)); // {a: 1} true
console.log(tata, Object.isFrozen(tata)); // {a: 3} false
```

raises this error when compiling:

> error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'a' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

Even though the compilation succeeds and the code works as expected.
Is there a way to not get this error?
Is there a better way to copy a frozen object into a non-frozen version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation on the type definition of `assign`:

```
assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
```

The definition will return `T & U` as the result type, and  this will keep all details of both `T` and `U` including whether their fields are readonly or not (in fact all field should be mutable after the call to `assign`)

To make things more complicated there is no way to remove `readonly` from the type up until 2.8 (unreleased at the time of writing, will be released in March 2018 but you can get it via `npm install -g typescript@next`).

In typescript 2.8 we can do the following:

```
type Mutable<T>  = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
const tata: Mutable<typeof toto> = Object.assign({}, toto);
tata.a = 3;
```

Until 2.8 you might be better off having a separate type for the unfrozen version, either explicitly or by having a variable that holds the unfrozen version:

```
const totoProto = {a: 1};
const toto = Object.freeze(totoProto);
const tata: typeof totoProto = Object.assign({}, toto);
tata.a = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you try this?

```
const tata = Object.assign({}, Object.create(toto));
```

Comment: But this will remove type info .. might as well cast the original result to `any` and you get the same effect without calling `create`

Comment: Yes you are right, i missed about type info. Thanks for comment!

Comment: yes it is a dirty solution that solves it in the same way that `const tata: any = Object.assign({}, toto)` does... so by losing the type info like you mentioned